# How do I fix GitHub displaying readme.md instead of my create-react-app game?

Tags: reactjs, github

GitHub displaying readme.md instead of my app (created with create-react-app).

Tried moving index.html and index.js around, expected to display my app (a game) instead of the readme.md, but nothing changed.

Please kindly advise.

Github repo: https://github.com/0mgABear/tictactoe

Comment: are you trying to render your react app on your github repository page?

Comment: I see the index.html when I look at https://0mgabear.github.io/tictactoe/

Comment: @Damzaky Yes I am trying to render my react app. I've also followed the instructions here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

It was previously working with no issues.

Comment: @Benjamin: I looked at some other resources and some suggested where the index.html is located could be a contributing issue, tried shifting it around to no avail.